Append new row if value doesnt exist by grouping columns

I want to by grouping year and month, every year and month have all distinct account and if that account doest exist in that year and month, the value will be 0.
How should I solve this?

Use out = df.set_index(['year','month', 'account']).unstack(fill_value=0).stack().reset_index()

Code
use merge + how=cross to create cartesian product
out = (df[['year', 'month']]
       .drop_duplicates()
       .merge(df[['account']].drop_duplicates(), how='cross')
       .merge(df, how='left')
       .assign(value=lambda x: x['value'].fillna(0))
)

out
    year  month account  value
0   2023      1    1234    1.0
1   2023      1    9372    3.0
2   2023      1    8735    0.0
3   2023      1    0000    0.0
4   2023      2    1234    2.0
5   2023      2    9372    0.0
6   2023      2    8735    2.0
7   2023      2    0000    0.0
8   2024      1    1234    0.0
9   2024      1    9372    0.0
10  2024      1    8735    9.0
11  2024      1    0000    6.0


Example Code
import pandas as pd

data = {'year': [2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024],
        'month': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
        'account': ['1234', '9372', '1234', '8735', '8735', '0000'],
        'value': [1, 3, 2, 2, 9, 6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

